# Find available bandwidth from Python or C++

Tags: c++, python

I am trying to get the available bandwidth from my PC.

Suppose I'm streaming a video at 2 Mbps and my network card is of 100 Mbps, my program should tell me that 98 Mbps is available.

Is it easy to do in C++ or Python? And how can I find the available bandwidth using any of the suggested programming language. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your bandwidth is most likely limited by your internet connection, and not by your network card. Why do want to tell them they're wasting bandwidth? What does your application do?

Comment: This will almost certainly be OS-specific. Which OS(es) do you need to support?

Comment: @aix...Oh i'm sorry as I forgot to mention the OS. My OS is Ubuntu/Linux.My application just finds the current utilization of my network card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLoad is written in C++ and supports monitoring bandwidth use on various Unix like operating systems.

You might find some inspiration at https://github.com/revnode/nload

Comment: thanks george. definitely found some inspiration. Is it possible for me to get python to run nload and "grep" the output?

Comment: Ok i got it! :) Thanks george!

Comment: Doesn't NLoad measure used bandwidth instead of available bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many factors that will influence the available bandwidth: your hardware (network card, router, WiFi stability, cabling), what you are doing (other downloads, machine load) and what is happening elsewhere (bandwidth to target server, ISP issues, etc.). And all of those can change at any moment in time to make things more interesting. The end result is that there is no way to useful way calculate the available bandwidth. The best you can do is to try downloading (or uploading, depending on what direction you are interested in) some testdata to the target server and see what bandwidth you can use. Keep in mind that TCP has a speeds up over time so you need to run your test for a while to get the real available bandwidth.

Comment: so let's say...im uploading data to server www.ABC.com and my network card is of 100 Mbps, how can I find how much bandwidth I have left IF only im just uploading?

Comment: @AmaarBokhari: I'd avise you to pick up a book on network technology first. E.g. `www.ABC.com` will respond with `ACK` messages to confirm that your upload is working, so there's always some other traffic. And you cannot control how much that is. Furthermore, your statement that "my network card is [of] 100 Mbps" ignores full/half-duplex behavior and the difference between upload and download speed (as you commonly have with ADSL)

Comment: @MSalters...you misunderstood my question. I'm pretty much familiar with network technology. But anyways, since George has guided me in the right direction, i won't re-explain my question. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: A simple approach that might be sufficient is to just upload as much as you can during 60 seconds and then determine what bandwidth was used in the last 20 seconds. That will give you an estimate that should at come at least somewhat close to the available bandwidth.